# How do I get the area of a graphics circle?

Tags: python, graphics, area

I'm trying to take the inner area of the yellow circle and outer area of the rest of the circles. But I'm not sure how to compute the area of a circle in a graphics.

```
from graphics import *
import math
def main():
win = GraphWin('Archery Target',300,300)
center = Point(150,150)

w = Circle(center,100)
w.setFill('White')
w.draw(win)

b = Circle(center,80)
b.setFill('Black')
b.draw(win)

bl = Circle(center,60)
bl.setFill('Blue')
bl.draw(win)

r = Circle(center,40)
r.setFill('Red')
r.draw(win)

y = Circle(center,20)
y.setFill('Yellow')
y.draw(win)


msg1 = Text(Point(100, 280), "inner area = ", innerA)
msg1.draw(win)


msg = Text(Point(150, 20), "Click anywhere to close")
msg.setTextColor('red')
msg.draw(win)
win.getMouse()
win.close()

main()
```

Comment: "Get" the area to do what?

Comment: Im trying to find a print the area but im not sure how to go about doing this from a graphics window.

Comment: Do you mean "paint" (or fill) the area with a color? Also, the `graphics` module you're using isn't a standard one. What is it and where did you get it?

Comment: In case you really need the area (and not filling/recoloring instead) Hope you know `area of circle = Pi*r*r` in the same units squared as you got the radius `r` defined (so most likely in `[pixels^2]`) where `Pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795` If you got any scaling you need to apply it to `r` before computation. If you need the precise pixel count of rasterization then you need to count them by 2 nested `for` loops.

Comment: @Spektre i know that the area of a circle = pi*r**2, but Im new to programming and the problem is I dont know how to implament that into a graphics, like how am I to get the radius of a graphics cirlce? or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Comment: @MistahDylan Iam not familiar with python nor graphics lib you are using but I think `Circle(center,100)` means `r=100` so you already know all the radiuses you need